# Dynamically create HttpRequestHandling inside a spring application

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-integration

Im working on the requirement of being able to dynamically add spring integration httpInbound listeners on a running web application, currently I'm creating an HttpRequestHandlingController bean through the following code:

```
            DefaultListableBeanFactory beanFactory = getBeanFactory();
            // first we crate the definition for the connection factory
            BeanDefinitionBuilder builder = getBeanBuilderForClass(HttpRequestHandlingController.class);
            builder.addConstructorArgValue(true);
            builder.addPropertyReference("requestChannel", channelName + "In");
            builder.addPropertyReference("replyChannel", channelName + "Out");
            builder.addPropertyValue("supportedMethods", methodNames);
            builder.addPropertyValue("requestPayloadType", payloadType);
            builder.addPropertyReference("messageConverters", "converters");
            builder.addPropertyValue("viewName", "jsonView");
            builder.addPropertyValue("path", path);

            beanFactory.registerBeanDefinition(name, builder.getBeanDefinition());

            getLogger().info("HTTP Inbound Gateway succesfully created: " + name);

            AbstractEndpoint comp =(HttpRequestHandlingController) getNewContextBeanFactory().getBean(name);
            comp.start();
```

per logs, seems everything seams alright:

```
INFO  inbound-hce-rest-connector - Creating new HTTP Inbound Gateway: inbound-hce-rest-connectorInboundHttp
INFO  inbound-hce-rest-connector - HTTP Inbound Gateway succesfully created: inbound-hce-rest-connectorInboundHttp
DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'inbound-hce-rest-connectorInboundHttp'
DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating instance of bean 'inbound-hce-rest-connectorInboundHttp'
DEBUG o.s.i.h.i.HttpRequestHandlingController - 'Jaxb2RootElementHttpMessageConverter' was added to the 'defaultMessageConverters'.
DEBUG o.s.i.h.i.HttpRequestHandlingController - 'MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter' was added to the 'defaultMessageConverters'.
DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Eagerly caching bean 'inbound-hce-rest-connectorInboundHttp' to allow for resolving potential circular references
DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'inbound-hce-rest-connectorConvChannelIn'
DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'inbound-hce-rest-connectorConvChannelOut'
DEBUG o.s.b.BeanUtils - No property editor [org.springframework.http.HttpMethodEditor] found for type org.springframework.http.HttpMethod according to 'Editor' suffix convention
DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'converters'
DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'integrationGlobalProperties'
DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Invoking afterPropertiesSet() on bean with name 'inbound-hce-rest-connectorInboundHttp'
DEBUG o.s.i.h.i.HttpRequestHandlingController - Unable to locate MultipartResolver with name 'multipartResolver': no multipart request handling will be supported.
DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'integrationEvaluationContext'
DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Finished creating instance of bean 'inbound-hce-rest-connectorInboundHttp'
INFO  o.s.i.h.i.HttpRequestHandlingController - started inbound-hce-rest-connectorInboundHttp
```

the path is set on runtime an here you can see an snapshot fo the debug

[image: Debug of set values]

also, this context runs on top of this servlet definition:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>InboundGCRestServices</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath:/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>

    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>InboundGCRestServices</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/service/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

But when I send a request, I get this on the server:

```
DEBUG o.s.w.s.DispatcherServlet - DispatcherServlet with name 'InboundGCRestServices' processing POST request for [/inbound-grand-central/service/hceServices/processIsoTransaction]
WARN  o.s.w.s.PageNotFound - No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/inbound-grand-central/service/hceServices/processIsoTransaction] in DispatcherServlet with name 'InboundGCRestServices'
DEBUG o.s.w.s.DispatcherServlet - Successfully completed request
```

From this article http://duckranger.com/2012/04/spring-mvc-dispatcherservlet/ I understand that the servlet get the mapping initialized at start time, since the creation of my listener can happen at any time AFTER servlet initialization, how can I get the servlet refresh and "see" the new definitions, or even is this the right approach? a embebed container would like jetty be more appropriate? pls advice.

Answer (score 0):

You can't modify the `DispatcherServlet`'s `handlerMappings` at runtime.

I haven't done it, but it looks like you can set `detectAllHandlerMappings` to `false` and write your own `HandlerMapping` and add an instance to the context with bean name `handlerMapping`.

You could then add your new beans to your custom handler mappings class.

You might be able to use the logic from the `IntegrationRequestMappingHandlerMapping` - it's `final` so you can't subclass it.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a try this week and let you know if it works, but makes perfect sense